# wsprintf limits me to 1024 characters?

Tags: c, winapi

Based on the documentation of `wsprintf`, it limits the output buffer to 1024 bytes. What if the text I need to store is greater than 1024 bytes?  How can I extend this limit, or what is an alternative for me to use that doesn't require me to use lstrcat or similar?

```
char output[4096];
wsprintf(output, "%s", input); // assume input is a piece of text > 1024 characters
printf(output); // only prints the first 1024 characters
```

How can I make all the characters from input be copied into output, exceeding the limit of `wsprintf` of 1024 bytes?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: Could you provide an actual code snippet you were trying to get working? Having specific details will make it easier to provide a solution or work-around.

Comment: Use StringCchPrintf or StringCchPrintfEx instead ... its limit is 2147483647

Comment: Is `StringCchPrintf` a light api? What I mean is, is the execution speed as fast an a similar function written in asm?

Comment: Do you have reason to worry about the performance of formatted print? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Comment: If you need memcpy, then use memcpy ... why the heck would you be using formatted output?

Comment: " the other functions which you have suggested me have crashed my process" -- then you're calling them incorrectly.

Comment: @JimBalter I'm simply showing you what I'm looking for along the lines of what I wrote... I need a function which does the concatenation of a formatted string with as little computation as possible...Why are you getting mad?

Comment: Your problem is that you are mixing ANSI and Unicode. There is no 1024 limit, you are looking in the wrong place to find the error.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: you might be thinking of `swprintf`, not `wsprintf`.

Comment: Um, you're the only one mad here ... I merely stated facts. Again, we can't help you if you don't demonstrate your actual requirements. formatted print is inconsistent with "as little computation as possible".

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am using `wsprintfA()`, ANSI , my compiler settings are set to multi-byte by default

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Yes there is ... read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx (which notes that it's obsolete)

Comment: Your version of `memcpy` is not *lightweight*: its prototype is incorrect, make unnecessary tests, saves far too many registers and uses suboptimal byte based copy code.  What is your target OS? How do you measure performance? Do you do any profiling?

Comment: @charlie and others, yes I was I thinking of `swprintf` which is recommened for unicode.

Comment: @chqrlie He deleted that from his question. Below he writes about `wsprintf(output, "%d + %d = %d", 1, 2, 3)` so he seems to be looking for something more complex. Of course, there's no way to guide him to optimality if he isn't clear about what he wants to optimize.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard functions `snprintf` and `swprintf`.  They have no such limitation:

```
char output[4096];
int length = snprintf(output, sizeof output, "%02000d", 1);
 // should print 2000 zeros:
printf("length=%d output=%s\n", length, output);
```

`swprintf` is the equivalent function for `wchar_t`:

```
wchar_t output[4096];
int length = swprintf(output, sizeof output / sizeof *output, "%02000d", 1);
 // should print 2000 zeros:
printf("length=%d output=%Ls\n", length, output);
```

Comment: How can I concatenate more than one arguement in snprintf, like for wsprintf I can do `wsprintf(output, "%d + %d = %d", 1, 2, 3);`. How can I achieve the same with snprintf?

Comment: @TigerJoe Have you read the documentation? snprintf takes a format argument just like wsprintf ... all the *printf functions do.

Comment: `snprintf` does the same conversions as `sprintf`, but it is *safe* as you pass the size of the destination buffer.  Do not use `sprintf` nor `wsprintf` for reason,  Microsoft limited the maximum output of `wsprintf` as a lame attempt to prevent buffer overflows, but programmers still use it in a risky way by passing a shorter buffer.

Comment: If available, there's also the `snwprintf_s` function per [**K.3.9.1.3**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: @AndrewHenle: that's true, but `snwprintf_s()` does not buy you much over `swprintf()`.  `%n` handling is disabled and behavior on output exceeding destination buffer size is more complicated, defaults to aborting the program instead of just truncating the output.

Answer (score 2):

`wsprintf()` is deprecated.  Use one of the [Strsafe functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468908.aspx) (`StringCbPrintf/Ex()` or `StringCchPrintf/Ex()`) instead.  They support an output buffer up to 2,147,483,647 characters in size (`STRSAFE_MAX_CCH`).

Comment: It's not what I need. This is too heavy for what I need to have done. It crashes the process.

Comment: @TigerJoe If it crashes the process then you're misusing it. And if you want help, post your actual code or something equivalent that illustrates your requirements ... what you posted is just a string copy.